# Does a Solidity Interface Contract need to implement all functions, or only the function subset used in the contract that implements the interface?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, upgrading, interfaces

Let's assume the following:

- There is a master contract A, an interface contract IB, and a slave contract B
- A implements IB to allow upgrading B without redeploying A

**Question:**

Does IB need to have all functions of B, or only the ones used by A?

Comment: Interfaces don't implement contracts: contracts implement interfaces.  What is the inheritance chain here?  A->IB->B ?  Seems odd and IB doesn't have to implement anything.  Or is it an interface I with contracts A and B implementing I?  What goes in I would be what you require both A and B to implement: A and B can each have extra functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to my experience in the following code

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c23f944b139a76693abbae261ad577b8

it is enough implementing those ones you are using. In the example:

```
/// ---- dataStorage interface
contract dataStorage {
    function getBalanceOf(address _account) constant returns (uint256 balance);
    function setBalanceOf(address _account, uint256 _value);
}
```

Comment: did you compile & deploy it?

Comment: Yes, using browser-solidity + metamask:

It is deployed at  https://testnet.etherscan.io/address/0x2bdaa67309293f99644dff29fbc2bb53915d069e